# sql query by most recent date

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am listing item from a database, in an array of many database items. I know what I am trying to do can be done by having separate table, however for this requirement, i wanted to see if it is possible to do the following.

My code is:

```
$sql_list  ="SELECT  *
    FROM ".$this->tables_rma."
    ORDER BY dateCreated DESC";
```

This returns an array of data in the table which is good, however I have multiple entries of the same item with different entities.

So what i want to be able to do is select one of each entry, by its most recently updated row of data.

Is this possible, or am i simply trying to cut corners?

Comment: Yes it is possible but you have to mention your database type (mySQL, MSSql,...) and your table structure.

Comment: o ok. my apologies. MySQL. im not sure what u mean by table structure. as this is a fairly minor section it simply is a self contained table. although I am using it in codeignitor and is in the model that wants to produce an array of data to display in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have ID unique field and YourITEM field then:

```
select * from YourTable t1 where id = 
   (select id from YourTable t2 
     where t2.YourItem=t1.YourItem 
     order by DateCreated desc, id desc limit 1)
```

If you don't need last DateCreated value in your select then just:

```
select distinct YourItem from YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SELECT DISTINCT [column]` or `GROUP BY [column]`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with LIMIT 1?

```
$sql_list  ="SELECT  *
    FROM ".$this->tables_rma."
    ORDER BY dateCreated DESC LIMIT 1";
```